# Crear archiv .log con resultados Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Voy a traar de explicarme lo más claro posible, la situación es esta: tengo la siguiente estructura de proyecto:

[image: estructura de proyecto]

El directorio donde se ubican estas dos carpetas es code.

Dentro de ISV1/testing tengo los scripts .py de los test que deseo ejecutar (hechos con selenium) desde server-test/script.py.

De cada test tengo que obtener el output en un .log y guardarlo en ISV1/testing/log.

Tampoco tengo idea de cómo puedo ejecutar los scripts de python que contienen los test, ya que estan en otro directorio, no logré encontrar la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quizá puedas hacer algo como esto, lo he usado con python 2.7, no estoy seguro de su comportamiento sea el mismo en 3.5

```
import subprocess

proceso = subprocess.Popen(["python",  "/path/script.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
salida = proceso.communicate()[0]
print(salida)
```

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y me devuelve este error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo php artisan dusk'. Tengo instalado todo, está en condiciones

Comment: Edite la respuesta, creo que no fui muy claro en como se debería de ejecutar el script, una vez que tengas la salida del test, lo que queda sería pasarla al log, ojala te pueda servir

Comment: Funciona perfecto, lo único que me devuelve: b'' en la consola..